# Strings read from .txt being redefined for no apparent reason in C

Tags: c

I'm stuck working on a college project in c:

```
char ID[10],tipo[10],origen[50],destino[50],hora_salida[5],hora_llegada[5];
int duracion;
float precio;
FILE *fp;
chdir("BASEDATOS");
fp=fopen(nombreArchivo,"rt");
fseek(fp,228*sizeof(char),SEEK_SET);
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"spanish");
gotoxy(1,1);
fscanf(fp,"%s",ID);
fscanf(fp,"%s",tipo);
fscanf(fp,"%s",origen);
fscanf(fp,"%s",destino);
printf("%s\n",destino);
fscanf(fp,"%s",hora_salida);
printf("%s\n",destino);
```

(function gotoxy() works as intended and does not interact with the variables or the txt file)
So I have an issue with this particular function within the project, I need to read some strings of a .txt file, and the problem appears when I scan the "destino" variable. For some reason the value changes when I scan the next string (hora_salida), although I haven't used the variable "destino" at all.

The first lines of the txt file are in this format:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/aaHwo]

Note that I use fseek to skip the first three lines which are of no use.

The outcome of the code is the following:

```
Madrid-Chamartín\n
(blank space)
```

So destino is getting the desired value at first, but gets blank afterwards.

Comment: You know string in C are null terminated, right? And the `\0` character requires space to be stored.

Comment: Just solved, thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: Generally, never use `%s` in `fscanf` without a width; always use `%5s` or similar...

Answer (score 0):

`hora_salida` and `hora_llegada` are not big enough. These fields are 5 characters, so you need 6 bytes to allow for the null terminator.

```
char hora_salida[6], hora_llegada[6];
```

Because of this, you're causing undefined behavior due to buffer overflows.

Comment: Wow can't believe i just lost a whole afternoon for such a stupid mistake, i was focusing my attention on the previous fscanf() rather than the others.

Comment: Tools like valgrind can help detect this.